# Сочетание с производным предлогом

Tags: пунктуация

**Мне помимо курсов и самостоятельной подготовки еще нужен балл аттестата.**

Нужны ли тут какие-либо запятые?

Answer (score 1):

Конструкции с предлогами "помимо, кроме" раньше обособлялись в зависимости от того, обозначали ли они "включая" или "исключая". Помнится, что позже от этой путаницы решено было избавиться, и теперь все конструкции с вышеназванными предлогами обособляются. В данном предложении обособление особенно "просится", так как налицо осложнение однородными членами: Мне, помимо курсов и самостоятельной подготовки, еще нужен балл аттестата.

Comment: >все конструкции с вышеназванными предлогами обособляются  
  
Нет, императивного правила нет. Есть рекомендация:

*Обычно обособляются (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу) обороты с отглагольными предлогами включая, исключая, исходя из, начиная с, невзирая на, несмотря на, смотря по, судя по, а также ограничительно-выделительные обороты с предлогами вопреки, за исключением, кроме, независимо от, помимо. *
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1/

Answer (score 0):

"балл аттестата" - не очень понятно. 
А так - все нормально. Обсосоления оборота с "помимо" не требуется, хотя и возможно.